# Setting View tag to for retrieve sibling View

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a set of `View States` that each contain a `CheckBox` view and an `EditText View`.  When the user checks the `CheckBox`, I'd like to set the visibility of the `EditText`.

To get a handle of the `EditText` from the `CheckBox`, I just put the `EditText` as a tag on the `CheckBox` in `OnCreate()`:

```
// In OnCreate()
v = f1.findViewById(R.id.imgNotes);
v.setTag(f1.findViewById(R.id.noteText));
v.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Later, in `onClick()` I retrieve the `EditText` from the tag:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    super.onClick(v);
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.imgNotes:
            View noteText = (View) v.getTag(); 
            if (null != noteText)
            {
                if (noteText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    noteText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    noteText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;

    …
```

Everything is working fine.  I was just wondering if there is a better way.  Or is this okay? Or is this the ideal way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, no issues, but as a practice, avoid tagging views to other views. Few other ways you can try.

**Field variable**

Declare two private members, for EditText and CheckBox, and directly access them, whenever a checkbox is clicked. It works fine if lets say you have one pair of CheckBox and EditText, but the code gets messy if too many check_box and edit_text ids are wired around.

**Custom view**

Define a [custom view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) class which holds such View state pairs, that way you can manage multiple such pairs, with each custom view holding business logic inside that view, thereby providing flexibility to add more behaviours in future, just edit this class.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` save `EditText` to a global variable likes this:

```
mEditText = (EditText) f1.findViewById(R.id.noteText)
```

Then in your onClick just use `mEditText` instead of `noteText`